# how to remove smallest value digit from an integer and return the rest of it without using string

Tags: java

how to remove smallest value digit from an integer and return the rest of it without using string.Like if we have number 4412,then reomive the 1 and return 442.
I did the coding for extracting the smallest number but dont know how to combine rest of them.

```
public class RemoveSmallestDigit {

    static int testcase1 = 4487;
    static int testcase2 = 1111;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        RemoveSmallestDigit testInstance = new RemoveSmallestDigit();
        int result = testInstance.removeSmallestDigit(testcase1);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    //write your code here
    public int removeSmallestDigit(int num){
        int small=9;
        int digit=0;
        while(num!=0){
            digit=num%10;
            num=num/10;
            if(digit<=small){
                small=digit;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(small);
        return small;

    }
}
```

Comment: extracted digits from the number but unable to combine them again

Comment: Now that you know the value of the smallest digit, can you write a loop which finds that digit?

Comment: What do the requirements say when there are two instances of the smallest digit? For example, what do you do with 44121?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you break this down into steps.  For example, you might do something like

1. Find the digits of a number and store as an array
2. Find the lowest digit and remove it from the array
3. Convert the new array back to a number

Of course, you can come up with your own steps if you find something that makes more sense to you. The main idea is to break a problem down into smaller problems. If you have trouble with any of these smaller problems, please come back with more questions.

Comment: Sry but I cannot use array.I have to solve it without array

Comment: @user3109998: Even without an array, code-guru's suggestion can be used. But also, would you mind showing us your latest attempt at a solution, any attempt? Your original question looks like a beg for code, and I'm pretty sure that's not your intention. Prove me right by showing us what you've done.

Comment: public class RemoveSmallestDigit {
 
  static int testcase1 = 4487;
  static int testcase2 = 1111;
  
  public static void main(String args[]){
   RemoveSmallestDigit testInstance = new RemoveSmallestDigit();
   int result = testInstance.removeSmallestDigit(testcase1);
   System.out.println(result);
  }
  
  //write your code here
  public int removeSmallestDigit(int num){
   int small=9;
   int digit=0;
   while(num!=0){
    digit=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    if(digit<=small){
     small=digit;
    }
   }
   System.out.println(small);
   return small;
   
  }
}

Comment: @user3109998 As my example shows, you should first describe the steps you need to take in English or your native language.

Answer (score -1):

```
public  int removeSmallerdigit( int a)
{
  int smalldigit=0;

int ReverseNumber=0;
int finalNumber=0;
int digit=0;
       while(a>0)
       { 
               digit=a%10;
                 a=a/10;
               if(smalldigit>digit)
                  {
                     smalldigit=digit;
                  }
        ReverseNumber=ReverseNumber*10+digit;
       }

       while(ReverseNumber>0)
         {
              digit=ReverseNumber%10;
                ReverseNumber=ReverseNumber/10;
               if(smalldigit!=digit)
                  {
                     finalNumber=finalNumber*10+digit;
                  }

       }
    return finalNumber;
}
```